# Visual Studio MSBuild.exe Debug adding unused dlls to bin of all web projects

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a large solution, including many projects of varying types, web, windows services, class libraries etc.

When debugging a windows service, using f5 in visual studio, I've noticed that it's adding unused dlls into the bin folder of ALL web-projects, which is causing a could not load file or assembly error, when making a http request to a site.

In particular it's adding System.Web.WebPages and System.Web.WebPages.Deployment into the bins of all web projects. Neither of these dlls are used or referenced in my projects, the only references I have are System.Web and System.Web.Razor.

This behaviour does not happen on a normal build or rebuild, only when debugging through visual studio.

I have a short term fix which is tools -> options -> projects and solutions -> build and run -> On Run, when projects are out of date: set to never build

However I would like to get to the bottom of why when running debug that the build differs and adds these ddls?